# Why does the following trigger need three similar statements at the top?

Tags: oracle, triggers

In the declaration section of a trigger I'm studying, I see these three lines at the beginning :

```
Prompt drop Trigger ONL_ACCT_DEL_TRIG;
DROP TRIGGER ONL_ACCT_DEL_TRIG;
Prompt Trigger ONL_ACCT_DEL_TRIG;
/* etc */
```

;

what is the difference between them? I don't see any significant difference among them, so I was wondering what's happening.

Comment: `prompt` is a SQL*Plus command. It doesn't really do anything to the trigger. Check the manual for details: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve032.htm#i2698182

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  - Ok, understood.  So I can just ignore those two outer lines I'm guessing. (the code is run in TOAD)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Prompt` is used to display things, read more [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12032.htm).

The first line displays a text, the second line drops the trigger, while the third line displays another text. Try it out. Create a trigger and then a script, which runs the 3 mentioned commands, but with your test trigger.